# Corona SDK: how to remove list view item listener?

Tags: listview, coronasdk, ontouchlistener

I created listview in Corona:

```
myList = tableView.newList{
            data=data,
            default="res/blueBg.png",
            backgroundColor={255,2552,255},
            onRelease=listButtonRelease,
            top=135,
            bottom=100,
            --data in rows etc.
         }
```

and added onRelease listener:

```
function listButtonRelease( event )
    self = event.target
    local id = self.id
    print(self.id)

    storyboard.gotoScene( "scene2", "slideLeft", 200 )
end
```

But after I switch to scene2 listeners still respond to touch events.
I tried to use this on exitScene:

```
myList:removeEventListener( "onRelease",  listButtonRelease)
```

but it doesn't work for some reason. So how do I remove listener from listview and its items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foolproof workaround.

Set a flag `sceneExited = true`   in your exitScene listener.

In your listButtonRelease function, check

```
if sceneExited then return end
```

and set the flag `sceneExited = false` in your enterScene listener

Comment: great! I should have thought about it :)